# What do the symbols in service --status-all mean?

Tags: services, documentation

I really miss the graphical "Services" tool from older versions of Ubuntu, but I understand why it had to go. I always have terminals open anyway, so I use (because I have to now, I guess) `service --status-all` to see what services are running. This would be ok except that the command produces output like the following:

```
 [ + ]  winbind
 [ ? ]  wpa-ifupdown
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

I'm guessing that those symbols mean something like listening, blocked, or stopped, but which is which? More importantly, why doesn't the man page say?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To provide a shallow and unsatisfactory answer your first question:

- The command `service --status-all` literally runs `service <name> status` for each service that supports the `status` command. Convention is for these to return success if the service is running and an error otherwise. A `[ + ]` is drawn upon success and a  `[ - ]` upon error.
- The `[ ? ]` is drawn for services that don't mention a `status` command in `service <name>`.

As you might have anticipated, I learned this by reading the source code.

To address the real issue—the lack of documentation—I suggest filing a polite bug report about the manpage on Launchpad. `ubuntu-bug sysvinit-utils` should get you started.

Comment: Thank you! I got as far as logging in to launchpad, but then I wasn't sure which package to specify. I have a hard time trying to read source code :(

Answer (score 11):

services-admin was removed from the default installation some releases ago due to the fact that it was unable to handle Upstart jobs.

In 10.10, a utility to manage services has returned: `jobs-admin` will be able to control and configure both Upstart and System V jobs/services. If you'd like to give this a try now, check out the [jobs-admin/jobservice PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jpeddicord/+archive/jobs).

As for the symbols in your question, I believe `+` is running/enabled, `?` is configured to start but may not be currently running (run-once, maybe), and `-` is likely disabled or not running.

*Disclaimer: I am the developer of jobs-admin and jobservice and worked on it as a summer of code project for Ubuntu. It is not available on a default installation, but I'd like to work towards that for 11.04.*

Comment: I really wanted to check both your and aendruk's answers, but sadly I can't. Since he gave an answer more specific to my question, I checked his answer. I'm happy to hear of your project and look forward to working with jobs-admin. Will it by any chance have a textual or ncurses interface available? Thanks for all you do!

Comment: No worries. And yes, I am planning on writing an ncurses interface for use on the server in the next release. :)