# Service --status-all --> what does the column with [ ? ],[ + ], and [ - ] mean?

Tags: services

If I run the command "service --status-all", each (running?) service is listed in column format. The first column has either a [ ? ], [ + ], or [ - ] before the service name. What does this column represent? What does ?, +, and - mean?

Sorry if this is a simple question. I searched online for ~30 minutes before just coming here and asking.

I even found this: [What do the symbols in service --status-all mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4879/what-do-the-symbols-in-service-status-all-mean) where the "correct" answer states "It draws a [ + ] or [ - ] depending on whether the exit status was zero or nonzero, respectively.".

So, I guess my new question is what does status zero and nonzero(!?!?!) mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well those are just exit codes. After something has done running, it can return an 8-bit integer (0-255) to indicate *how* it exited.

- Zero (which is implied if nothing is returned) means the application got to the end of what it was supposed to do and exited naturally.
- Non-zero codes (1-255) can mean whatever the application wants. The man page (`man <command>`) will usually show you what these codes mean.

In terms of the question, don't overthink it:

- `+` means it's running,
- `-` means it isn't (it *might* have crashed - it might never have started), and
- `?` means the services doesn't have a `status` command, so there's no way the service command can work out what's what.

Comment: I totally agree with your answer (+1), but I just can't understand why `sudo service --status-all 2>&1 | grep ssh` outputs `[ - ]  ssh` even when I run this command from SSH? Or why `sudo service --status-all 2>&1 | grep lightdm` outputs `[ ? ]  lightdm` when `sudo service lightdm status` works like a charm?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu To guess, I think might be is a legacy `/etc/init.d` issue. On my serially upgraded computer, `/etc/init.d/ssh status; echo $?` shows non-zero (bad, not running) and `initctl list` doesn't show SSH. On my 14.04 box `initctrl` *does* show SSH but `service` still can't read the status. Also remember that `initctrl` works for Upstart and `service` is part of `sysvinit-utils`. It's not the clearest of pictures but I think that might go some way to explain *some* of the quirks. I'm sure the move to systemd will clear everything up D:

Comment: I thought a negative exit code could be returned as well, or is that for non-service scripts only?